# BigQuery SQL: Sum of first N related items

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to know the sum of a value in the first n items in a related table. For example, I want to get the sum of a companies first 6 invoices (the invoices can be sorted by ID asc)

Current SQL:

```sql
SELECT invoices.company_id, SUM(invoices.amount)
FROM invoices
JOIN companies on invoices.company_id = companies.id
GROUP BY invoices.company_id
```

This seems simple but I can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider also below approach

```
select company_id, (
    select sum(amount)
    from t.amounts amount
  ) as top_six_invoices_amount
from (
  select invoices.company_id, 
    array_agg(invoices.amount order by invoices.invoice_id limit 6) amounts
  from your_table invoices
  group by invoices.company_id
) t
```

Comment: That's fantastic, it's helped a lot thanks. As a cheeky follow up, if I then wanted to only include companies that actually have had 6 invoices, is that possible?

Comment: sure. add `having count(*) = 6` to inner select (after `group by`). if still help needed  - please post new question with all relevant details :o)

Answer (score 1):

You can create order row numbers to the lines in a partition based on invoice id and filter to it, something like this:

```
with array_table as (
 select 'a' field, * from unnest([3, 2, 1 ,4, 6, 3]) id
 union all
 select 'b' field, * from unnest([1, 2, 1, 7]) id
)

select field, sum(id) from (
   select field, id, row_number() over (partition by a.field order by id desc) rownum
   from array_table a
) 
where rownum < 3
group by field
```

More examples for analytical examples here:

https://medium.com/@aliz_ai/analytic-functions-in-google-bigquery-part-1-basics-745d97958fe2

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts